# Python loop indexing

Tags: python, loops, indexing

I'm working through a book on Python3 and linear algebra.  I'm trying to take a string with the format 'name junk junk 1 1 1 1 1' and make a dictionary with the name in the and the numbers converted from strings to ints.  i.e. {name:[1,1,1,1,1]}  But I can't quite figure out the loop, as I'm a python newbie.  Here's my code:

```
string = 'Name junk junk -1 -1 1 1'
for i, x in string.split(" "):
        if i == 0:
            a = x
        if i > 2:
            b = int(x)
```

Running that code nets the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Ideally I'd also like it to be a comprehension.  But I can probably figure that part out if I can get the loop.

Comment: In Python, assignments are statements (only), not expressions. I'm not sure what you are trying to do with a and b, but it could be difficult to turn it into a single comprehension, since the first element of a comprehension is an expression.

Comment: What about that "junk junk"? Just junk?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you mean to use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)?

```
for i, x in enumerate(string.split(" ")):
     # ...
```

Using a list comprehension:

```
tokens = string.split() # Splits by whitespace by default, can drop " "
result = {tokens[0]: [int(x) for x in tokens[3:]]} # {'Name': [-1, -1, 1, 1]}
```

Comment: I never thought about doing it that way.  Thanks!!